# Failed to parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I tried to parse this:

```
{"event":[{"event_id":"9","title":"event 10","welcome_logo":"20140715130727_252.png"}],"succeed":1}
```

This is my code:

```
NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://loc**host/summit/event_login.php"];
NSData *dataURL=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResult=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *element=[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *title = [element objectForKey:@"title"];
NSString *image = [element objectForKey:@"welcome_logo"];
```

But this guy came and disturbs me:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e7d010'

So I'm wondering what I did I do wrong. I tried to google it and many said that I assume to use an array when the data is actually a dictionary. Is that true? So what do I need to do?

Comment: The error is self explanatory that `jsonArray` is `NSDictionary` not `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
NSArray *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *element=[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

to

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *events = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"event"];
if ([events count] > 0) {
    NSDictionary *element=[events objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

because your json data is in the form of dictionary. And `event` holds the list (array) of events. And do a count check before accessing `objectAtIndex:` from `events`.

Comment: sorry but that jsonArray isn't identified

Comment: Awesome, its worked very well pal. Thank you for you help. However i need to delete the if part because the element variable cannot be read by my NSString variable.

Comment: @Edward You are welcome.. Try to move the code that uses the element variable inside if part so that, if there is no element in `events` array it will not crash. Happy coding..